# Which grant type is used by default ASP.NET Core Identity Microsoft External account login?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an MVC application that is implementing external login using Microsoft account by following the tutorial here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0

The question I was asked and I am not able to find answer to is - which OAuth 2.0 grant type does this application use?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [the tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to create an Asp.net core application and use Microsoft Account Login. In the Login page, you can check the request url, the `response_type` is `code`, it means that by default Asp.net core Microsoft Account external login will use the OAuth 2.0 auth code grant:

[image]

By using the OAuth 2.0 auth code grant, the request like this:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read%20api%3A%2F%2F
&state=12345
&code_challenge=YTFjNjI1OWYzMzA3MTI4ZDY2Njg5M2RkNmVjNDE5YmEyZGRhOGYyM2IzNjdmZWFhMTQ1ODg3NDcxY2Nl
&code_challenge_method=S256
```

More detail information about OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow, see [Microsoft identity platform and OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).